# Question put on hold, should I have had a notification?

Tags: support

My question was put on hold but I didn't receive a notification. Should I have received one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notifications are not generated for this type of action.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Eric's answer, it is an unnecessary notification since you are expected to monitor your question, respond to comments and see if you get the answer you so desperately need. At least, this is the idea of those who create and evolve (Pokémon Go reference intended) the Stack Exchange network.